# Function definition not allowed here?

Tags: c++

i am a total newbie to c++.
i am writing this function but somehow it give me this error

```
Error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
```

My code is

```
int main() {
    //number is given num
    // power is raise to power
    int raiseTo(int number, int power)
    {
        for (int i=0;i<=power;i++)
        {       
            number=number*number;
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong. thanks.

Comment: Go through a basic tutorial. This is just wrong.

Comment: You are not performing *power* by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two major problems:

1. You should not implement a function inside a function
2. You are not performing the power algorithm correctly

Try this code instead:

```
int raiseTo(int number,int power)
{
    int result = 1;
    for (int i=0; i<power; i++)
    {
        result = result*number;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 2;
    int y = 3;
    int z = raiseTo(x,y);
    printf("%d^%d = %d\n",x,y,z);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard says:

> § 8.4.1/2 *[..]* A function shall be defined only in namespace or
>   class scope.

So what you're doing is simply not allowed.